# Remotely change the Region on a Windows 2008 R2 Server

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to remotely change the region on a Windows 2008 R2 Server through Powershell v2. Problem is that nothing happens.

Steps :

- Created an XML file with the `<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">` structure.
- Called it through `` & "C:\Windows\System32\control.exe" "intl.cpl,,/f:`"D:\temp\UKLocal.xml`"" ``
- Copied `D:\temp\UKLocal.xml` to the remote machine on its D drive.

Command line works OK locally.

Then I created a script which did the following :

`Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $HOSTNAME -Credential $PSCredential` ⇒ OK

`` C:\Windows\System32\control.exe "intl.cpl,,/f:`"D:\temp\UKLocal.xml`"" `` ⇒ No error, nothing happens (note the backticks to escape the quotes)

`Exit-PSSession` ⇒ OK

If I try to create a file on the remote folder with `Out-File`, the file gets created. This proves that I am connected and can issue PowerShell commands.

The provided account in the Credential object is local Admin on the remote machine.

Comment: Weird but could work: Create the file, and launch the command via `at +00:01`

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your proposal, could you elaborate a little more please ?

Comment: Create a bat file with this command written as plain text, without fancy backticks before quotes, to be executed via cmd. Create a scheduled task (`at /?` for help) to run that bat file as you at next minute, wait and check.

Comment: Although it's a nice idea, I cannot use it because I need to connect though PowerShell (running a puppet script).

Answer (score 0):

Which regional settings are we talking about?
As far as I know regional settings are "per user" settings and not "per machine" making what you are trying to accomplish kind of impossible in the current way.

Comment: Run control.exe, Type "Regional" and change location in the first tab and in the second tab as well. The settings must should at least change the settings for the current user, which currently fails.